# Determine the convergence of $ \sum\limits_n\frac{(1/4)^n (2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ and $ \sum\limits_n\frac{(-1/4)^n (2n)!}{(n!)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I'm trying to analyze the ratio of convergence of the following power series, I also want to know if the series converges at the endpoints of R (radius of convergence).

$$ \sum_{n=0}^ \infty \frac{x^n (2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$

By the ratio test, it is easy to see that$\ R=1/4$, that is, the series converges for$\ |x|<1/4$

I want to know what happens with the series at$\ x=1/4$ and$\ x=-1/4$

At$\ x=1/4$

$$ \sum_{n=0}^ \infty \frac{(1/4)^n (2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$

Do I have to use the ratio test yet again?

Comment: I do not recommend using the ratio test again because it will give the limit of ratio $1$.

Comment: It's called a radius of convergence :-)

Comment: Divergence test may be useful.

Comment: What would you recomend @i707107 ?

Comment: I recommend using $(2n)!= (2n\cdot ( 2n-2 ) \cdots 6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2) \cdot ((2n-1)\cdot (2n-3) \cdots 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 1)$, and $2^n n! = 2n\cdot ( 2n-2 ) \cdots 4 \cdot 2$.

Comment: *Hints:* $\enspace (1)\enspace $$\sum\limits_n\left(\frac{(1/4)^n (2n)!}{(n!)^2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\right)$ is convergent and therefore $\sum\limits_n (\frac{(1/4)^n (2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ divergent. $\enspace (2)\enspace $ $ \sum\limits_n\frac{(-1/4)^n (2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ is convergent by *Leibniz criteria* (= *alternating series test*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with using stirling approximation
$$\sum_{n=0} \frac{(1/2)^{2n}(2\pi2n)^{1/2}(2n)^{2n}e^{-2n}}{2\pi n (n)^{2n}e^{-2n}} = \sum_{n=0}1/(\pi n )^{1/2}$$
diverges because p series (p<1).
However, I am not sure if the my answer is true or not.
edit: Besides, for the x=-1/4, alternating series converges. Because its limit at infinity is 0 and monotonic decreasing sequence.

Comment: It's more or less o.k. (+1). More details would be an advantage.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\cos x\right)^{2n}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\cdot \frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}\sim \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}} \tag{1}$$
from which it follows that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}z^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}\tag{2} $$
for any $z\in(-1,1)$. The LHS of $(2)$ is convergent at $z=-1$ by Leibniz' test and divergent at $z=1$.