# For which values of $x$ is $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!\,x^n}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

> For which values of $x$ is $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!\,x^n}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$$ convergent or divergent?

• I tried $x=-1$ and i tested it by using [Comparison Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_test) and [Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) but that was diverge. This series is not absolutely converge for $x=-1$ if I am right.

• Any suggestions?

Comment: This is the Taylor series of $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}},$ if you start with $n=0.$ See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for more details.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2817711/determine-the-convergence-of-sum-limits-n-frac1-4n-2nn2-and) could help.

Answer (score 3):

If $x\ne0$, we have\begin{align}\lim_{n+\infty}\frac{\left|\frac{(2(n+1))!x^{n+1}}{2^{2(n+1)}((n+1)!)^2}\right|}{\left|\frac{(2n)!x^n}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\right|}&=\lim_{n+\infty}\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{4(n+1)^2}|x|\\&=|x|\end{align}and therefore the series converges absolutely if $|x|<1$ and diverges if $|x|>1$.

The sequence $\left(\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ decreases because, by the computation made above, if you divide the $(n+1)$<sup>th</sup> term by the $n$<sup>th</sup>, you get$$\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{4(n+1)^2}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}<1.$$Also, it follows from the equality of the previous line that$$2^{2n}(n!)^2=\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{2j-1}{2j}.\tag1$$Now, note that$$\left(\frac{2j-1}{2j}\right)^2<\frac j{j+1},$$since this means that $4j^3-3j+1<4j^3$; in other words,$$\frac{2j-1}{2j}<\sqrt{\frac j{j+1}}.\tag2$$But then it follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that$$\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}<\prod_{j=1}^n\sqrt{\frac j{j+1}}=\sqrt{\frac1{n+1}},$$and so, by the squeeze theorem, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}=0$. Since it decreases and its limit is $0$, it follows from the Leibniz test that your series converges when $x=-1$.

But it diverges when $x=1$. You will find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1887601/446262).

Answer (score 3):

hint:
use Rabbe's test for$ x=-1$

Answer (score -1):

$${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(2n)!x^n}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}} = {\frac{1+{\sqrt{1-x}}}{\sqrt{1-x}}}$$

It's will be convergent if $\vert{x}\vert < 1$, by **Ratio Test**

Note that this can be checked using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com), with this formula: `series (((2n)!x^n)/(2^(2n)(n!)^2)) from 1 to inf`